# How to insert date in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I use in my code `myDatepicker`

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="myDatepickerInput">Due time </label>

                        <div>
                            <div class="datepicker" data-initialize="datepicker" id="myDatepicker">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="myDatepicker" type="text" name="date">
```

Here is some code. But i can't insert date in database. In mysql i used `type='date'`in my controller `$works -> date = $request['date'];` It's insert `0000-00-00` 
Where is the problem and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try as:

```
$works->date =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $request['date'])));
```